# MINUS operation not working as expected in Stored Procedure, Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have Oracle Stored procedure, which validates the data between two tables based on some manipulations. The Procedure has been working wrong since a recent change.(Added a new column) Not sure why is the reason. Tried to Analyses the data randomly, and we are sure there are no special characters in any of the columns.

I copied my table's spec and recreated the scenario.

Inserting Data

```
 BEGIN
 FOR I IN 1..4 LOOP
  INSERT INTO AR_TABLEA VALUES('Name'||I,21+I,'Address'||I);
  INSERT INTO AR_TABLEB VALUES('Name'||I,21+I,'Address'||I);
end loop;
 END;
 /
```

trying a MINUS operation

```
SELECT * FROM AR_TABLEB
MINUS
SELECT * FROM ar_tableA ;
```

Output:

```
NAME              AGE ADDRESS
---------- ---------- --------------------
Name1              22 Address1
Name2              23 Address2
Name3              24 Address3
Name4              25 Address4
```

But Expected Result shouldn't be "no rows selected" ?

This is just a test data, my original tables is big enough.

Thanks in advance, for any help!

Comment: It could be the conflict between a `CHAR` and a `VARCHAR` column. Can you post the table description please?

Comment: desc AR_TABLEA and desc AR_TABLEB gives you exactly same results?

Comment: SQL> desc AR_TABLEA
 Name                    Null?    Type
 ----------------------- -------- ----------------
 NAME                             VARCHAR2(10)
 AGE                              NUMBER
 ADDRESS                          CHAR(1000)

SQL> desc AR_TABLEB
 Name                    Null?    Type
 ----------------------- -------- ----------------
 NAME                             VARCHAR2(10)
 AGE                              NUMBER
 ADDRESS                          VARCHAR2(1000)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this please.

```
SELECT trim(name),age,trim(address) FROM AR_TABLEB
MINUS
SELECT trim(name),age,trim(address) FROM ar_tableA ;
```

If the Above Query worked for you, then one of the table has a column with `CHAR` data type, with the other having the  same column has `VARCHAR`.

Please note that, A `CHAR` datatype always hold the contents with its maximum possible size.
Say if you declare it as `CHAR(10)` and save a character `'A'` in it, it gets saved as
`'A         '` (Appended with Spaces).

So either `LPAD` the `VARCHAR2` column with spaces or `TRIM` the `CHAR` column when comparing or merging these data types.

Comment: you are right, as stated earlier address column was modifed to be varchar2 so AR_TABLEA has CHAR and AR_TABLEB has VARCHAR2.